# My method can't return boolean

Tags: java

I am newbie in java.

Here is my code:

```
public boolean endsLy(String str) {
  if(str.length()>=2){
    if(str.substring(str.length()-2).equals("ly")) return true;
  }
  else return false;
}
```

but compiler gives:

```
Error:  public boolean endsLy(String str) {          
This method must return a result of type boolean
```

Possible problem: the if-statement structure may theoretically 
allow a run to reach the end of the method without calling return.
Consider adding a last line in the method return some_value; 
so a value is always returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not handling the branch where `(str.length()>=2`, but `!str.substring(str.length()-2).equals("ly")`. Remove the `else` from the final `return` statement:

```
public boolean endsLy(String str) {


  if(str.length()>=2){

    if(str.substring(str.length()-2).equals("ly")) return true;

  }
  return false;

}
```

An even simpler alternative (also less prone to the kind of error you are having), is to have only a single `return` statement:

```
public boolean endsLy(String str) {
    return str.length()>=2 && str.substring(str.length()-2).equals("ly");
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. That is probably better. The posted solution is just the one that would require the minimum modification to fix the original code.

Comment: @ Mad Physicist: Deserves a second upvote, but SO won't let me. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Or simply :

```
public static boolean endsLy(String str) {
     return str.length()>= 2 && str.substring(str.length()-2).equals("ly");
}
```

You might also check if the `String` is not null.

```
return str != null && str.length()>= 2 && str.substring(str.length()-2).equals("ly");
```

Answer (score 0):

here a correction:

```
 public boolean endsLy(String str) {
     if(str.length()>=2){

        if(str.substring(str.length()-2).equals("ly"))
         return true;
         else
         return false;

      }
      else{ 
      return false;
      }

}
```

Comment: That's an awfully complicated way to write `if (str.length()>=2) { return str.substring(str.length()-2).equals("ly"); }`.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that there might be a possibility that the function will **not return anything under some circumstances.**

so if this condition => `if(str.length()>=2)` stands true the code will enter into it. Now if this condition is false => `if(str.substring(str.length()-2)` the function will have nothing to return. So this is a wise thing that the error prompted.

**This means that not all conditions in this function return a bool value. There is a chance that conditions may occur when function does not have anything to return.**

Answer (score 0):

Avoid multiple false return statement as return value is true only for condition if(str.substring(str.length()-2).equals("ly")). Following code is for reference.

```
 public boolean endsLy(String str) {


      if(str.length()>=2){

        if(str.substring(str.length()-2).equals("ly")) 
            return true;

      }
    return false;

    }
```

Comment: Please add a 1 line description to your answer as well. Check [answer]?

Answer (score 0):

because you do not have a boolean value is returned in case **!str.substring (str.length () -2). equals ("ly")**

if you want to check that your chain is composed of four characters in the last two are "ly" you can use the following codes:

```
public boolean endsLy(String str) {
    if (str.length() == 4 && str.endsWith("ly"))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```